# JS (jquery) выполнение функции каждые 200 мсек с паузой каждые 5 секунд

Tags: javascript

Как на jquery реализовать выполнение функции каждые 200 милисекунд, и делать паузу в выполнении каждые 5 секунд?
Пытался сделать что-то с помощью setInterval() но результат не совсем тот что нужен:

```
function do()
{
// функция выполняется каждые 200 милисекунд
}

setInterval(do, 200);

function pause()
{
//функция выполняется каждые 5 секунд.}

setInterval(pause, 200)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function a() {
  console.log('a')
};

let interval;
let intervalTime = 200;
let delayTime = 5000;
let stopTimeout;
let startTimeout;

function start() {
  interval = setInterval(a, 200);

  startTimeout = setTimeout(stop, delayTime + intervalTime);
  clearTimeout(stopTimeout);
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(interval);

  stopTimeout = setTimeout(start, delayTime - intervalTime);
  clearTimeout(startTimeout);
}

start();
```